# Magento 1.9 Trusted Shops with reviews

Tags: php, magento

I have the problem when I integrate Trusted Shops in a static block or via the plugin of Trusted Shops. The evaluation and the Stars are not on the Trusted Shops badge then the man has to insert the following Div element with the matching variables on the checkout page.

```
<div id="trustedShopsCheckout" style="display: none;">
<span id="tsCheckoutOrderNr">2016-05-21-001</span>
<span id="tsCheckoutBuyerEmail">mein.kunde@mail.de</span>
<span id="tsCheckoutOrderAmount">4005.95</span>
<span id="tsCheckoutOrderCurrency">EUR</span>
<span id="tsCheckoutOrderPaymentType">VORKASSE</span>
<span id="tsCheckoutOrderEstDeliveryDate">2016-05-24</span>
</div>
```

Now the question where can I find the variables for it or is there a simpler way to integrate that?

greetings
Leon

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the checkout/success.phtml

```
/********************************************
 * TRUSTED SHOPS BUYERS PROTECTION
 *
 * Variables needed for Trusted Shops PopOut-Card,
********************************************/
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$grandTotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
$currencyCode = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
$paymentType = $order->getPayment()->getMethod();
?>
<div id="trustedShopsCheckout" style="display: none;"> 
  <span id="tsCheckoutOrderNr"><?php echo $orderId ?></span> 
  <span id="tsCheckoutBuyerEmail"><?php echo $email ?></span> 
  <span id="tsCheckoutBuyerId"><?php echo $customerId ?></span> 
  <span id="tsCheckoutOrderAmount"><?php echo $grandTotal ?></span> 
  <span id="tsCheckoutOrderCurrency"><?php echo $currencyCode ?></span>
  <span id="tsCheckoutOrderPaymentType"><?php echo $paymentType ?></span>
  <span id="tsCheckoutOrderEstDeliveryDate"></span>
</div>
```

If you want to add Product Reviews too you have to add the following code before the final `</div>`

```
  <!-- product reviews start -->
  <?php foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem): ?>
    <?php $product = $orderItem->getProduct(); ?>
    <span class="tsCheckoutProductItem">
      <span class="tsCheckoutProductUrl"><?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?></span>
      <span class="tsCheckoutProductImageUrl"><?php echo $product->getImageUrl() ?></span>
      <span class="tsCheckoutProductName"><?php echo $product->getName() ?></span>
      <span class="tsCheckoutProductSKU"><?php echo $product->getSku() ?></span>
    </span>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <!-- product reviews end -->
```

Info:
You can also add GTIN, MPN and Brand. But this depends to your product structure. See http://www.trustedshops.de/shopbetreiber/integration/product-reviews/ for this